# How to show icons from FontAwesome in Angular's innerHTML content?

Tags: json, angular, font-awesome

I have Font Awesome in my Angular 14 app implemented as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome . I use <fa-icon [icon]="faIconName"> semantics. I also use few languages on my website and I load translations through json files. In templates I use semantics like <span [innerHTML]="here_i_have_key_to_translate | translate | safeHtml" where I use translate service and pipe which let me show in template forbidden code like *fa-icon* (default this is earased from json html, just like 'style' attribute). How can I use Font Awesome icons in json? Below there is example of json, code.

language json from assets\i18n:

```
"key_1":"<p><b>example text</b><br /><fa-icon [icon]=\"faPhoneSquare\"></fa-icon> +43 123 123 923</p>",
"key_2":"<p><fa-icon [icon]=\"faPhoneSquare\"></fa-icon> +44 123 123 123</p>",
"key_3":"<p><fa-icon [icon]=\"faPhoneSquare\"></fa-icon> +43 123 123 123</p>",
```

template:

```
<section>
    <h4 [translate]="'header_1'"></h4>
    <p>
        <fa-icon [icon]="faEnvelope" class="me-2"></fa-icon> Some static text with icon on left which displays fine
    </p>
</section>
<section [innerHTML]="'key_1' | translate | safeHtml"></section>
<section [innerHTML]="'key_2' | translate | safeHtml"></section>
<section [innerHTML]="'key_3' | translate | safeHtml"></section>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslationAppService } from '../../../common/services';
import { faPhoneSquare, faEnvelope } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})

export class ContactComponent {

  faPhoneSquare = faPhoneSquare;
  faEnvelope = faEnvelope;
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how Angular is supposed to work.

Angular is in charge of handling your HTML. You are not supposed to write HTML templates that you send to Angular. It simply does not work because it's not supposed to work like that.

Just write your HTML in your HTML files and only provide the data you need from your API (in this case the phone number it seems).

Comment: It worked like charm when font awesome was loaded from angular.json and was injected to DOM head but now, as you said, I shoud cut my json to litle pieces and every icon should be in template. It's not good information for me because I have a lot of icons in translations

Comment: Your icons are not translated, your data is.

Comment: I understand that it is good practice to install font awesome and do everything as they said in docs but there are problems in ex. with pseudo classes, with icons in translations (as in my topic) and looking from dev-side something which was relative very easy (yes, I know, it wasn't optimal) and friendly now is very difficult and time consuming

Comment: That's what happens when you do something you're not supposed to so ...

Comment: I'll defend myself ;) In previous versions of angular suggested way to implement font awesome was to import them just like I wrote (in angular.json or even in index.html in head section). So it isn't that simple to say that this is something user not supose to do. Now it hasn't compatibility with previous versions. That's all.

Thank you for sugestions. I did what you said and effect is good (smaller js files, no fonts files, etc). I hope that page will by faster. Thank you.

Comment: I am not saying you are importing them wrong, I am saying you're not supposed to send html from your api like that.